# Create line guides over HTML using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, wpbakery

I try to draw vertical guides on my HTML content created in Wordpress WPBakery Page Builder. After creating the content I want to "put" vertical guides on page overl all content and have no idea how i can do that.

Theoretically i can use `border-left: 1px solid #ccc` and `z-index: 9999` for every `col-3` in pure Bootstrap 4.5, but Visual Composer using alternative markup and I don't know how I can do that.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Guides from top to bottom like that: http://ar-demo.rodzyk.com